# Install Octave 64bit in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, octave

Currently working to install Octave 64 bit by following this article : https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Compiling-Octave-with-64_002dbit-Indexing.html

so i come to first step compiling LAPACK (3.6.1) package so i edit make.inc as follow :

```
####################################################################
#  LAPACK make include file.                                       #
#  LAPACK, Version 3.6.1                                           #
#  June 2016                                                       #
####################################################################
#
SHELL = /bin/sh
#  
#  Modify the FORTRAN and OPTS definitions to refer to the
#  compiler and desired compiler options for your machine.  NOOPT
#  refers to the compiler options desired when NO OPTIMIZATION is
#  selected.  Define LOADER and LOADOPTS to refer to the loader and 
#  desired load options for your machine.
#
#  Note: During a regular execution, LAPACK might create NaN and Inf
#  and handle these quantities appropriately. As a consequence, one 
#  should not compile LAPACK with flags such as -ffpe-trap=overflow.
#

FORTRAN  = /usr/bin/gcc 
OPTS = -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC
DRVOPTS  = $(OPTS)
NOOPT = -g -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC
LOADER = $(FORTRAN)
LOADOPTS = -Wl,-rpath=/usr/bin/gcc/lib
RANLIB = ranlib

#
#  Comment out the following line to include deprecated routines to the
#  LAPACK library.
#
#MAKEDEPRECATED = Yes
#
# Timer for the SECOND and DSECND routines
#
# Default : SECOND and DSECND will use a call to the EXTERNAL FUNCTION ETIME
# TIMER    = EXT_ETIME
# For RS6K : SECOND and DSECND will use a call to the EXTERNAL FUNCTION ETIME_
# TIMER    = EXT_ETIME_
# For gfortran compiler: SECOND and DSECND will use a call to the INTERNAL FUNCTION ETIME
TIMER    = INT_ETIME
# If your Fortran compiler does not provide etime (like Nag Fortran Compiler, etc...)
# SECOND and DSECND will use a call to the INTERNAL FUNCTION CPU_TIME
# TIMER    = INT_CPU_TIME
# If neither of this works...you can use the NONE value... In that case, SECOND and DSECND will always return 0
# TIMER     = NONE
#
#  Configuration LAPACKE: Native C interface to LAPACK
#  To generate LAPACKE library: type 'make lapackelib'
#  Configuration file: turned off (default)
#  Complex types: C99 (default)
#  Name pattern: mixed case (default)
#  (64-bit) Data model: LP64 (default)
#
# CC is the C compiler, normally invoked with options CFLAGS.
#
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O3
#
#  The archiver and the flag(s) to use when building archive (library)
#  If you system has no ranlib, set RANLIB = echo.
#
ARCH     = ar
ARCHFLAGS= cr
RANLIB   = ranlib
#
#  Location of the extended-precision BLAS (XBLAS) Fortran library
#  used for building and testing extended-precision routines.  The
#  relevant routines will be compiled and XBLAS will be linked only if
#  USEXBLAS is defined.
#
# USEXBLAS    = Yes
XBLASLIB     =
# XBLASLIB    = -lxblas
#
#  The location of the libraries to which you will link.  (The 
#  machine-specific, optimized BLAS library should be used whenever
#  possible.)
#
BLASLIB = ../../blas$(PLAT).a
CBLASLIB     = ../../libcblas.a
LAPACKLIB    = liblapack.a
TMGLIB       = libtmglib.a
LAPACKELIB   = liblapacke.a
```

then run

> sudo make blaslib lapacklib tmglib

i get this output :

```
hoka@Hoka-HP:~/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1$ sudo make blaslib lapacklib tmglib
( cd BLAS/SRC; make )
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/BLAS/SRC'
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c isamax.f -o isamax.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sasum.f -o sasum.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c saxpy.f -o saxpy.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c scopy.f -o scopy.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sdot.f -o sdot.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c snrm2.f -o snrm2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c srot.f -o srot.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c srotg.f -o srotg.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sscal.f -o sscal.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sswap.f -o sswap.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sdsdot.f -o sdsdot.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c srotmg.f -o srotmg.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c srotm.f -o srotm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sgemv.f -o sgemv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sgbmv.f -o sgbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ssymv.f -o ssymv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ssbmv.f -o ssbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sspmv.f -o sspmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c strmv.f -o strmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c stbmv.f -o stbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c stpmv.f -o stpmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c strsv.f -o strsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c stbsv.f -o stbsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c stpsv.f -o stpsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sger.f -o sger.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ssyr.f -o ssyr.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sspr.f -o sspr.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ssyr2.f -o ssyr2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sspr2.f -o sspr2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c sgemm.f -o sgemm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ssymm.f -o ssymm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ssyrk.f -o ssyrk.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ssyr2k.f -o ssyr2k.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c strmm.f -o strmm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c strsm.f -o strsm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c idamax.f -o idamax.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dasum.f -o dasum.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c daxpy.f -o daxpy.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dcopy.f -o dcopy.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ddot.f -o ddot.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dnrm2.f -o dnrm2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c drot.f -o drot.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c drotg.f -o drotg.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dscal.f -o dscal.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dsdot.f -o dsdot.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dswap.f -o dswap.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c drotmg.f -o drotmg.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c drotm.f -o drotm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dgemv.f -o dgemv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dgbmv.f -o dgbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dsymv.f -o dsymv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dsbmv.f -o dsbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dspmv.f -o dspmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dtrmv.f -o dtrmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dtbmv.f -o dtbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dtpmv.f -o dtpmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dtrsv.f -o dtrsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dtbsv.f -o dtbsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dtpsv.f -o dtpsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dger.f -o dger.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dsyr.f -o dsyr.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dspr.f -o dspr.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dsyr2.f -o dsyr2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dspr2.f -o dspr2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dgemm.f -o dgemm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dsymm.f -o dsymm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dsyrk.f -o dsyrk.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dsyr2k.f -o dsyr2k.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dtrmm.f -o dtrmm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dtrsm.f -o dtrsm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c scabs1.f -o scabs1.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c scasum.f -o scasum.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c scnrm2.f -o scnrm2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c icamax.f -o icamax.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c caxpy.f -o caxpy.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ccopy.f -o ccopy.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cdotc.f -o cdotc.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cdotu.f -o cdotu.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c csscal.f -o csscal.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c crotg.f -o crotg.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cscal.f -o cscal.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cswap.f -o cswap.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c csrot.f -o csrot.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cgemv.f -o cgemv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cgbmv.f -o cgbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c chemv.f -o chemv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c chbmv.f -o chbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c chpmv.f -o chpmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ctrmv.f -o ctrmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ctbmv.f -o ctbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ctpmv.f -o ctpmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ctrsv.f -o ctrsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ctbsv.f -o ctbsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ctpsv.f -o ctpsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cgerc.f -o cgerc.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cgeru.f -o cgeru.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cher.f -o cher.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c chpr.f -o chpr.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cher2.f -o cher2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c chpr2.f -o chpr2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cgemm.f -o cgemm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c csymm.f -o csymm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c csyrk.f -o csyrk.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c csyr2k.f -o csyr2k.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ctrmm.f -o ctrmm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ctrsm.f -o ctrsm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c chemm.f -o chemm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cherk.f -o cherk.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c cher2k.f -o cher2k.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dcabs1.f -o dcabs1.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dzasum.f -o dzasum.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c dznrm2.f -o dznrm2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c izamax.f -o izamax.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zaxpy.f -o zaxpy.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zcopy.f -o zcopy.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zdotc.f -o zdotc.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zdotu.f -o zdotu.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zdscal.f -o zdscal.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zrotg.f -o zrotg.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zscal.f -o zscal.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zswap.f -o zswap.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zdrot.f -o zdrot.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zgemv.f -o zgemv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zgbmv.f -o zgbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zhemv.f -o zhemv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zhbmv.f -o zhbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zhpmv.f -o zhpmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ztrmv.f -o ztrmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ztbmv.f -o ztbmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ztpmv.f -o ztpmv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ztrsv.f -o ztrsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ztbsv.f -o ztbsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ztpsv.f -o ztpsv.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zgerc.f -o zgerc.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zgeru.f -o zgeru.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zher.f -o zher.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zhpr.f -o zhpr.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zher2.f -o zher2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zhpr2.f -o zhpr2.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zgemm.f -o zgemm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zsymm.f -o zsymm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zsyrk.f -o zsyrk.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zsyr2k.f -o zsyr2k.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ztrmm.f -o ztrmm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c ztrsm.f -o ztrsm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zhemm.f -o zhemm.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zherk.f -o zherk.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c zher2k.f -o zher2k.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c lsame.f -o lsame.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c xerbla.f -o xerbla.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c xerbla_array.f -o xerbla_array.o
ar cr ../../blas.a isamax.o sasum.o saxpy.o scopy.o sdot.o snrm2.o srot.o srotg.o sscal.o sswap.o sdsdot.o srotmg.o srotm.o sgemv.o sgbmv.o ssymv.o ssbmv.o sspmv.o strmv.o stbmv.o stpmv.o strsv.o stbsv.o stpsv.o sger.o ssyr.o sspr.o ssyr2.o sspr2.o sgemm.o ssymm.o ssyrk.o ssyr2k.o strmm.o strsm.o  idamax.o dasum.o daxpy.o dcopy.o ddot.o dnrm2.o drot.o drotg.o dscal.o dsdot.o dswap.o drotmg.o drotm.o dgemv.o dgbmv.o dsymv.o dsbmv.o dspmv.o dtrmv.o dtbmv.o dtpmv.o dtrsv.o dtbsv.o dtpsv.o dger.o dsyr.o dspr.o dsyr2.o dspr2.o dgemm.o dsymm.o dsyrk.o dsyr2k.o dtrmm.o dtrsm.o scabs1.o scasum.o scnrm2.o icamax.o caxpy.o ccopy.o cdotc.o cdotu.o csscal.o crotg.o cscal.o cswap.o csrot.o cgemv.o cgbmv.o chemv.o chbmv.o chpmv.o ctrmv.o ctbmv.o ctpmv.o ctrsv.o ctbsv.o ctpsv.o cgerc.o cgeru.o cher.o chpr.o cher2.o chpr2.o cgemm.o csymm.o csyrk.o csyr2k.o ctrmm.o ctrsm.o chemm.o cherk.o cher2k.o dcabs1.o dzasum.o dznrm2.o izamax.o zaxpy.o zcopy.o zdotc.o zdotu.o zdscal.o zrotg.o zscal.o zswap.o zdrot.o zgemv.o zgbmv.o zhemv.o zhbmv.o zhpmv.o ztrmv.o ztbmv.o ztpmv.o ztrsv.o ztbsv.o ztpsv.o zgerc.o zgeru.o zher.o zhpr.o zher2.o zhpr2.o zgemm.o zsymm.o zsyrk.o zsyr2k.o ztrmm.o ztrsm.o zhemm.o zherk.o zher2k.o lsame.o xerbla.o xerbla_array.o
ranlib ../../blas.a
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/BLAS/SRC'
( cd INSTALL; make; ./testlsame; ./testslamch; ./testdlamch; \
./testsecond; ./testdsecnd; ./testieee; ./testversion )
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL'
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c lsame.f -o lsame.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2 -funroll-loops -fdefault-integer-8 -fPIC -c lsametst.f -o lsametst.o
/usr/bin/gcc  -Wl,-rpath=/usr/bin/gcc/lib -o testlsame lsame.o lsametst.o
lsametst.o: In function `MAIN__':
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:53: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:53: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:53: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:83: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:83: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:83: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:83: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:84: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:84: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:84: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:81: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:81: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:81: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:81: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:79: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:79: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:79: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:79: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:77: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:77: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:77: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:77: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:75: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:75: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:75: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:75: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:73: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:73: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:73: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:73: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:71: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:71: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:71: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:71: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:69: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:69: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:69: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:69: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:67: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:67: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:67: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:67: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:65: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:65: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:65: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:65: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:63: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:63: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:63: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:63: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:61: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:61: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:61: undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_character_write'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:61: undefined reference to `_gfortran_st_write_done'
lsametst.o: In function `main':
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:88: undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_args'
/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL/lsametst.f:88: undefined reference to `_gfortran_set_options'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'testlsame' failed
make[1]: *** [testlsame] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hoka/Downloads/lapack-3.6.1/INSTALL'
/bin/sh: 1: ./testlsame: not found
/bin/sh: 1: ./testslamch: not found
/bin/sh: 1: ./testdlamch: not found
/bin/sh: 2: ./testsecond: not found
/bin/sh: 2: ./testdsecnd: not found
/bin/sh: 2: ./testieee: not found
/bin/sh: 2: ./testversion: not found
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'lapack_install' failed
make: *** [lapack_install] Error 127
```

how can i fix this? and is there simple way to configure 64 bit octave?

Comment: May I ask you why you don't install it from the repositories?

Comment: if you mean install octave from repo. it's installed by default 32 bit , so to enable 64 should compile packages in 64 bit machine as described in above article